# Make all pixel in raster have the same value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, raster-calculator

I have a raster file with two categories: category 12 (total count=350) and category 14 (total county = 500). The attribute table looks like this:

```
rowid Value Count
 0     12     350
 1     14     500
```

Is there any way I can give all pixel a value of 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [conditional statement](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z00000005000000) in the raster calculator as follows:

```
Con("your_raster.tif" >= 12, 1, "your_raster.tif")
```

This command assigns any value greater than or equal to 12 a value of 1.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Reclassify](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000sr000000) tool (Spatial Analyst).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than playing with conditional statements (which are fine, but not necessary here), I would just do the following in [raster calculator](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000z7000000.htm):

```
("raster.tif" * 0) + 1
```

Simple and effective.